# Langchain FAISS | Any solutions or alternatives for similarity search on vector DBs for slightly repetitive short words with numerics?

Tags: python, similarity, langchain, vector-database

So basically I am trying to search a cell line vector data base that has entries that look like this using langchain:

```
ID: 253F1

AC: CVCL_B513

SY: NA

OX: NCBI_TaxID=9606; ! Homo sapiens (Human)

CA: Induced pluripotent stem cell
```

There are easily tens of thousands of these entries in a text file that I store as a vector DB.

I find that if I do a similarity search on say the "Induced pluripotent stem cell", the similarity search always returns relevant documents. However, If i search 253F1 or CVCL_B513 its about a coin flip on whether the similarity search will return relevant documents.

The reason I need to do this form of search as opposed to a direct word match is because sometimes the input query will have varying forms of syntax eg: 253-F1 or 253.F1 or 253f1 scaled over thousands of entries.

Is there an alternative to approaching these short queries? Something that I might find getting better results?
I have tried using FAISS to create a vector DB and similarity search on it, but I fear that due to the nature of data too many elements appear similar.

Comment: At tens of thousands of documents, that's small enough that you could use brute force. For example, one algorithm would be to check if your search term is a substring of the database entry, looping over all database entries. No need for indexes. You might want try normalizing the search terms and items in the database - e.g if you remove all punctuation from the query and the database entries, is the query a substring of items in the database?